# Unable to locate any element using any locator in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have Page Object class now on the new page in which the methods are written. when I click on the link on first page to open up the new page, that works as expected. But, when I try to work with element on the new page all I get is `NullPointException` or `NoSuchElementException`.

I have tried using xpath and also tried class, and end up with the same issue.
Checked for Iframes and there are are none. The Id's are Unique and static.
I wrote the methods on the same class where I clicked the link to open new page to make sure driver is not "null".
Also I have added a thread sleep of 10 sec to make sure page is loaded properly

**Here is the html:**

```
<div class="lcc-form-field">

                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="40" tabindex="8" class="">        
                <div class="lcc-form-field">
                    <label class="lcc-form-label lcc-form-label-required" for="firstName">
                        First Name<sup class="sup-asterisk">*</sup>
                    </label><label class="lcc-form-label lcc-form-label-required" for="lastName">
                        Last Name<sup class="sup-asterisk">*</sup>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" maxlength="40" tabindex="9">
                </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the code:**

```
public  void enterFirstName(String name) {      
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(enterfirstName));
    enterfirstName.sendKeys(name);
}
```

so when I write the above snippet of code it throws null point exception
and when  I remove visibility of it throws no such element found.

Comment: Show more of your page object in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Its not gonna work, you are saying - " when i click on the link on first page to open up the new page. But, when I try to work with element on the new page all I get is NullPointException or NoSuchElementException." So u r still trying to work with elements on old page. You need to switch on the new opened tab first then try to click on your element.
Something like:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: He said "new page" which does not necessarily mean "new tab" or "new window"  I think his problem is much more complicated, but he doesn't provide enough code to know what's going on.  It's most likely his driver object and or a wait object.

Comment: Maybe u rifght, but he is getting NoSuchElementException, so I guess its not related driver. Lets see if he reply.